# Archive Installation for "Web Server Plug-ins for IBM WebSphere Application Server V9.0" instead of IM

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty, ibmhttpserver

I want to install the "Web Server Plug-ins for IBM WebSphere Application Server V9.0" without the IBM InstallationManager just with an archive file.

The archive installation was already possible for the "IBM HTTP Server V9.0" from e.g.: https://ak-delivery04-mul.dhe.ibm.com/sar/CMA/WSA/086do/0/9.0.0-WS-IHS-ARCHIVE-linux-x86_64-FP011.zip and just run the postinstall.sh. But for the aforementioned Web Server plugin, I cannot find an archive to download.

Does anyone know if such an Installation is possible?

Comment: Web Server Plug-ins for IBM WebSphere Application Server is really just one file so it doesn't make sense to really package an archive installation. For IHS, just pull mod_was_24_http.so from a linux-x86-64 installation and copy it to the new installations.  You would need to install from IM on one machine or extract from the IM repository to access the file.  You would also need to manually configure your webserver with directives for plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "IHS" archive install includes the WAS Plug-in files you need *for IHS* in a plugins/ sub-directory off the root. No 2nd download is required.

If you need the WAS WebServer Plug-ins for some other webserver, the IM install is your only option.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as you said, the WAS Webserver Plugin was right here:
**9.0.0-WS-IHS-ARCHIVE-linux-x86_64-FP011.zip\IHS\plugin\bin\mod_was_ap24_http.so**