# How can install and configure IBM HTTP Server v9 from archieve zip

Tags: apache, websphere, websphere-liberty, websphere-8, ibmhttpserver

I want to install the "IBM HTTP Server for IBM WebSphere Application Server V9.0" without the IBM InstallationManager just with an archive file.

I already downloaded the archive file 9.0.5-WS-IHS-ARCHIVE-win-x86_64-FP003.zip
and just run the postinstall.bat and I cannot install it .
So, Does anyone know how can install it?

This the message that get everytime i run this command

```
postinstall.bat
    postinst: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain 
    name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
    SERVERROOT_NATIVE=D:\Mohamed\Mohamed Nour\MohmedNour\Software\IBM WAS 
    ND\IHS
    SERVERROOT=D:/Mohamed/Mohamed Nour/MohmedNour/Software/IBM WAS ND/IHS
    PORT=80
    GSK7LIBDIR_NATIVE=D:\Mohamed\Mohamed Nour\MohmedNour\Software\IBM WAS 
    ND\IHS\gsk8\lib64
    GSK7LIBDIR=D:/Mohamed/Mohamed Nour/MohmedNour/Software/IBM WAS 
    ND/IHS/gsk8/lib64
    SERVERNAME=127.0.0.1
    postinst complete
```

here when access IBM HTTP Server

[click to view errors picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTxNn.jpg)

and also after register IHS in Admin Console and created unmanaged node for remote

when am access application from WAS it success but not when access through IHS

and also updated the http.conf configuration like :

```
<IfFile plugin/config/webserver1/plugin-cfg.xml>                             
LoadModule was_ap24_module C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\Plugins\bin\mod_was_ap24_http.dll                    
WebSpherePluginConfig C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\Plugins\config\webserver12\plugin-cfg.xml     
</IfFile>
```

and also web server created from console named webserver12

Comment: What goes wrong? You unzip to final destination then run postinstall.bat which works in-place. There's no subsequent installation needed.

Comment: @covener yes, i did that but it still not installed if there is another way to install it ?

Comment: What makes you say it's not installed? It's installed to whatever directory you ran postinstall.bat from. What can't you do from there?

Comment: @covener so can you please provide me the steps to install it then federate it to websphere application server ?

Comment: install is unzip and run postinstall.bat
Then configuration to be managed by tWAS is in the KC: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTJ_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.ihs.doc/ihs/tihs_install_config_twas.html

Comment: @covener  i get this msg after run postinstall.bat


postinst: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
SERVERROOT_NATIVE=D:\Mohamed\Mohamed Nour\MohmedNour\Software\IBM WAS ND\IHS
SERVERROOT=D:/Mohamed/Mohamed Nour/MohmedNour/Software/IBM WAS ND/IHS
PORT=80
GSK7LIBDIR_NATIVE=D:\Mohamed\Mohamed Nour\MohmedNour\Software\IBM WAS ND\IHS\gsk8\lib64
GSK7LIBDIR=D:/Mohamed/Mohamed Nour/MohmedNour/Software/IBM WAS ND/IHS/gsk8/lib64
SERVERNAME=127.0.0.1
postinst complete


so after that i must configure it with was or what?

Comment: and also when i run this : htpasswd -c conf/admin.passwd ihsadmin      i get this message htpasswd: cannot create file conf/admin.passwd @covener

Comment: Maybe on windows you need a backslash there?

Comment: what do you mean? @covener

Comment: @covener can you help me !?

Comment: No, sorry, you probably need commercial support not a programming forum like this.

Comment: @covener okay never mind .. can you provide me a download link for websphere plugins for WAS v9 to install it through IM instead of this archive file .. thank you

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.installation.zseries.doc/ae/cins_repositories.html

Comment: thanks @covener .. the problem is solved .. but what about SSL here .. ikeman here is not supported so what is the alternative in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just did what you want.
This is the procedure:

1. Download 9.0.5-WS-IHS-ARCHIVE-win-x86_64-FP003.zip
2. Unzip to target folder (recommended folder without spaces in the path)
3. Run postinstall.bat it displays the following:

   ```
   D:\install\WAS_90\IHS>postinstall.bat
   postinst: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
   SERVERROOT_NATIVE=D:\install\WAS_90\IHS
   SERVERROOT=D:/install/WAS_90/IHS
   PORT=80
   GSK7LIBDIR_NATIVE=D:\install\WAS_90\IHS\gsk8\lib64
   GSK7LIBDIR=D:/install/WAS_90/IHS/gsk8/lib64
   SERVERNAME=127.0.0.1
   postinst complete
   ```
4. Verify in httpd.conf that you have settings changed, for example search for server root settin: `ServerRoot "D:/install/WAS_90/IHS"`
5. Add IHS as service (you must have Administrator command line to do it):

`httpd.exe -k install -n IHS9A`

if you dont have admin rights just start server with the `httpd.exe` command

6. All done. Access your server via http://localhost
7. To federate to WebSphere App Server just follow usual instruction and provide your IHS unzipped folder as IHS install root.
8. To configure your plugin add the following lines to `httpd.conf`, the plugin file for IHS is located in `IHS\plugin\bin`. Example for Win:

   `<IfFile plugin/config/webserver1/plugin-cfg.xml>`
   `LoadModule was_ap24_module plugin/bin/mod_was_ap24_http.dll WebSpherePluginConfig c:/IHS/plugin/config/webserver1/plugin-cfg.xml`
   `</IfFile>`

These lines were correct after unzipping the IHS, but you manually messed that up, pointing to non existing `C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\Plugins` folder. While configuring IHS in WAS console you have to think and set the IHS home (eg. `C:\IHS`) and Plugin home (`c:\IHS\plugin`) correctly to the directory where you unzipped the IHS archive. This was already discussed here [Archive Installation for “Web Server Plug-ins for IBM WebSphere Application Server V9.0” instead of IM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56172426/archive-installation-for-web-server-plug-ins-for-ibm-websphere-application-serv)

Comment: i did it exactly what you said above but it still exist and i cannot access correctly the 
 IBM HTTP Server - i have done of federate it with was correctly but when access the app in web server i get 404 Not Found at IBM_HTTP_Server Server at localhost Port 83 Note get a look on the pic that i provided above it assume that i cannot access the IBM HTTP Server Administration

Comment: @mohamedn picture you attached, clearly shows that your http server is correctly up and running.If you cannot access apps deployed on WebSphere, it means you messed up the configuration not installation. You have to double check if you correctly configured webserver in the console, mapped apps, generated and propagated the plugin config file.

Comment: i configured all configuration like the Loadmodule file and WebSpherePluginConfig but in the Plugin folder the bin folder not created it just the config and logs folder so h tried many solutions but i cant .. so can you provide me a download link for websphere plugins for WAS v9 to install it through IM instead of this archive file

Comment: @mohamedn you dont need to install plugin for IHS, it is already in the archive. Check my updated answer.

Comment: thank you really helped me .. i understood what you said and it worked correctly after set IHS plugin home directory .